# How to check for identical strings in nested dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

Let me explain, I'm working in a bank and I'm trying to make a short python script that calculates the percentage of different shareholders.

In my example `EnterpriseA` is owned by different Shareholders directly and indirectly I stored it as it follows :

```
EnterpriseA = {'Shareholder0': {'Shareholder1': 25, 'Shareholder2': 31, 'Shareholder3': 17, 'Shareholder4': 27},
            'Shareholder3': {'Shareholder1': 34, 'Shareholder4': 66}}
```

I want to calculate how much each shareholders have of `EntrepriseA`, but I can't figure how to check if a shareholder appears multiple times in all my dictionaries.

What I'm thinking is checking if Shareholder1 appears multiple times if so calculate how many percentage he owns of EnterpriseA like this :

```
percentage = EnterpriseA['Shareholder0']['Shareholder1'] + (EnterpriseA['Shareholder0']['Shareholder3']*EnterperiseA['Shareholder3']['Shareholder1']/100)
```

[I've made a quick drawing for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyQJ9.png)

Comment: What is the maximum depth that can occur? Is it infinite?

Comment: As an aside, there is not enough info here to solve your problem. You don't know what percentages the parent `'Shareholder0'` and `'Shareholder3'` own in the structure of your current `dict` unless they're shared equally.

Comment: Can you share the output you are expecting. With a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the maximum depth is only ever singly nested then you can just write a little helper function.

Edit:
From what you've explained, `'Shareholder0'` is basically a list of direct enterprise shares.

I've modified the helper function and included a constant reflecting that.

```
ENTERPRISE_SHARES = 'Shareholder0'

EnterpriseA = {
    'Shareholder0': {
        'Shareholder1': 25, 
        'Shareholder2': 31, 
        'Shareholder3': 17, 
        'Shareholder4': 27
    },
    'Shareholder3': {
        'Shareholder1': 34, 
        'Shareholder4': 66
    }
}

def calc_percent(enterprise, name):
    parent_percents = enterprise[ENTERPRISE_SHARES]
    total_percent = parent_percents.get(name, 0)

    for shareholder, shares in enterprise.items():
        if shareholder != ENTERPRISE_SHARES and shareholder != name:
            total_percent += parent_percents[shareholder] / 100 * shares.get(name, 0)
    
    return total_percent

print(calc_percent(EnterpriseA, 'Shareholder1'))
print(calc_percent(EnterpriseA, 'Shareholder2'))
print(calc_percent(EnterpriseA, 'Shareholder4'))
```

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to answer my question !! Okay let me clarify, when talking about shareholder we talks about ranks so if you look at the picture i've made, The first Row is considered Rank0 so to clarify is should rename Shareholder0 as Rank0. For the second row consider its entrepriseB owning 17% of EnterpriseA. And enterpriseB is owned by Shareholder1 and Shareholder4 here is the real issue when you want to calculte shareholding parts you can have the same share holder in diffrent Ranks. I hope that clarifies my question ! And again thanks for taking the time to answer me !

Comment: And it can be infinite but this never occures lets say it never goes over 10 ranks !

Comment: Are you saying there can be multiple `'Shareholder0'`s?

Comment: No there is multiple Shareholder0, I added Shareholder0 as a way to identify the direct Shareholders of Enterprise A. As you edited your answer you got it right !